# Best way to turn python tkinter app with many packages/modules into EXE?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have created a tkinter app with a lot of imported modules. Now when I am trying to turn it into exe app with PyInstaller, I am having issue due to the modules that are imported.

Is there a better alternative to make this into a exe app which wont have issues with modules/pakcages?

Comment: Which module brings the issue.

Comment: "openpyxl" brings the issue

Comment: Why? Was it not packed while using `pyinstaller`, what are your code imports, are you importing `openpyxl` implicitly. Post the error code.